# Print new line with sed using variable

Tags: bash, variables, replace, sed, newline

I'm trying to print a new line after 'string' using the variable THIS into file.

```
sed -i '' 'string/a\
${THIS}
' "${f}"
```

It prints "${THIS}" into file, literally. I've tried using double quotes for sed but that leads to error message:

"sed: 1: "...": command a expects \ followed by text"

I've also tried to Google this and have been browsing this excellent forum but couldn't find anything.

Any idea, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
THIS="foo"
sed 's/string/string\n'"${THIS}"'/g' file.txt
```

Btw, if you are unsure I encourage you to be careful using the `-i` option. I would play with the sed command until I'm sure and only then use `-i` (which will overwrite the original file)

---

If you are replacing a literal string (no regex), the `replace` command might be better than sed here:

```
replace string "string"$'\n'"${THIS}" file.txt
```

Comment: First works but I want to insert THIS in a new line after the line which match the 'string'. Sorry if I was unclear!

Comment: Had to amend that because adding newline is not that simple on MacOSX but it worked! Thanks a lot, hek2mgl!

Comment: you are welcome. Glad that it works (even on mac ;) )